# How to connect an applet to an oracle database with firewall restriction

Tags: java, database, oracle, applet

I have created a java applet that I need to connect to an oracle database. My problem for security reasons the Server from which the from which the oracle database is created is protected with firewall to prevent direct connection the database. I have the database ip address and the port from which the database is running and the Service name but I don't know how to connect to that server so that I can access the database. This is my sample source code that am trying to connect to the database.

```
String dbip="xx.xx.xx.xx";
        String dbport="1523";
        String serviceName="servicenamexample";
        try {
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list="+
                     "(address=(protocol=tcp)(host="+dbip+")(port="+dbport+")))"+
                     "(source_route=yes)"+
                     "(connect_data=(INSTANCE_NAME="+serviceName+")))";
            password="mypass";
            username="myusername";
            OracleDataSource odbc=new OracleDataSource();
            odbc.setURL(url);
            odbc.setPassword(password);
            odbc.setUser(username);
            conn=odbc.getConnection();
            System.out.println("connection established !");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and this is the error that am getting.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:297)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:221)
```

Comment: If the server has a firewall, you need a rule in that firewall thar allows you to connect thougth it.

Comment: If you've got a ssh access, you can use ssh to port forward E.g : `ssh -L 1523:x.x.x.x:1523 ...` and then use *localhost* and port *1523*

Comment: @Duffydake what is a ssh port and how can I put in my url.

Comment: @jmurillo I don't have any firewall rule

Comment: @NemugaM [ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) is a protocol, you can't use it directly in your code (I mean with your current code). If you don't know what is ssh, i guess there is no ssh server on your server or you don't have access to it. My "solution" is if you've got a firewall (and you can't change rules) and a ssh access.

Comment: @Duffydake how else can I connect to the database because I don't have access to the firewall is a restriction made by the owner of the application

Comment: You must get an access to the *oracle server* otherwise you can't. You can run your app on the *oracle server* or ask owner to give you an access.

Comment: @Duffydake and is it possible to connect the applet to a weblogic datasource?

Comment: I don't know "weblogic datasource", I never used it.